# Couchbase + Scala + Java SDK : IndexOutOfBounds

Tags: java, scala, couchbase

I am relatively new to scala and to couchbase, but I need to learn both fast. Recently while trying to run a sample application using the Java couchbase SDK through Scala I have run into the following problem.

```
[cb-core-3-2] WARN com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore - Exception while Handling Request Events RequestEvent{request=null}
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1854, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.config.DefaultCouchbaseBucketConfig.nodeIndexForMaster(DefaultCouchbaseBucketConfig.java:135)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.node.locate.KeyValueLocator.calculateNodeId(KeyValueLocator.java:165)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.node.locate.KeyValueLocator.locateForCouchbaseBucket(KeyValueLocator.java:124)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.node.locate.KeyValueLocator.locateAndDispatch(KeyValueLocator.java:84)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.dispatchRequest(RequestHandler.java:219)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.onEvent(RequestHandler.java:176)
    at com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.onEvent(RequestHandler.java:71)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:129)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:71)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:354)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:349)
    at App$.main(Application.scala:28)
    at App.main(Application.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.couchbase.client.java.util.Blocking.blockForSingle(Blocking.java:71)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:354)
    at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseBucket.upsert(CouchbaseBucket.java:349)
    at App$.main(Application.scala:28)
    at App.main(Application.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[cb-core-3-1] WARN com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore - Exception while Handling Response Events null
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy.waitFor(BlockingWaitStrategy.java:45)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.ProcessingSequenceBarrier.waitFor(ProcessingSequenceBarrier.java:56)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[cb-core-3-2] WARN com.couchbase.client.core.CouchbaseCore - Exception while Handling Request Events RequestEvent{request=null}
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy.waitFor(BlockingWaitStrategy.java:45)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.ProcessingSequenceBarrier.waitFor(ProcessingSequenceBarrier.java:56)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

And this is the code that generated the error

```
import com.couchbase.client.java._
import com.couchbase.client.core.time._
import com.couchbase.client.java.document._
import com.couchbase.client.java.document.json._
import com.couchbase.client.java.query._
import com.couchbase.client.java.env.DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // Initialize the Connection
    // Connects to localhost
    val env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
  .connectTimeout(5000)
  .bootstrapCarrierEnabled(false)
  .build()

val cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "127.0.0.1")
// Opens the "default" bucket
val bucket = cluster.openBucket("default")

// Create a JSON Document
val user: JsonObject = JsonObject.create()
  .put("firstname", "Walter")
  .put("lastname", "White")
  .put("job", "chemistry teacher")
  .put("age", 50)

 val stored: JsonDocument = bucket.upsert(JsonDocument.create("walter", user));

// Load the Document and print it
// Prints Content and Metadata of the stored Document
println(bucket.get("walter"))

// Just close a single bucket
bucket.close();

// Disconnect and close all buckets
cluster.disconnect();
}
}
```

**EDIT:**

I am a little new to this but here is what I managed to get out of the debugger.

```
this = {DefaultCouchbaseBucketConfig@2385} "DefaultCouchbaseBucketConfig{name='testBucket', locator=VBUCKET, uri='/pools/default/buckets/testBucket?bucket_uuid=54c1356c57dea1d640837c678f87d5e4', streamingUri='/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/testBucket?bucket_uuid=54c1356c57dea1d640837c678f87d5e4', nodeInfo=[NodeInfo{, hostname=localhost/127.0.0.1, configPort=0, directServices={CONFIG=8091, QUERY=8093, VIEW=8092, BINARY=11210}, sslServices={CONFIG=18091, QUERY=18093, VIEW=18092, BINARY=11207}}], partitionInfo=PartitionInfo{numberOfReplicas=1, partitionHosts=[localhost], partitions=[], tainted=false}, tainted=false, rev=23}"
 partitionInfo = {CouchbasePartitionInfo@2391} "PartitionInfo{numberOfReplicas=1, partitionHosts=[localhost], partitions=[], tainted=false}"
  numberOfReplicas = 1
  partitionHosts = {String[1]@2428} 
  partitions = {ArrayList@2390}  size = 0
  forwardPartitions = null
  tainted = false
 partitionHosts = {ArrayList@2396}  size = 1
  0 = {DefaultNodeInfo@2425} "NodeInfo{, hostname=localhost/127.0.0.1, configPort=8091, directServices={CONFIG=8091, BINARY=11210, VIEW=8092}, sslServices={}}"
 nodesWithPrimaryPartitions = {HashSet@2397}  size = 0
 tainted = false
 rev = 23
 name = "testBucket"
  value = {char[10]@2422} 
  hash = 1241531676
 password = ""
  value = {char[0]@2421} 
  hash = 0
 locator = {BucketNodeLocator@2400} "VBUCKET"
  name = "VBUCKET"
  ordinal = 0
 uri = "/pools/default/buckets/testBucket?bucket_uuid=54c1356c57dea1d640837c678f87d5e4"
  value = {char[78]@2411} 
  hash = 0
 streamingUri = "/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/testBucket?bucket_uuid=54c1356c57dea1d640837c678f87d5e4"
  value = {char[87]@2420} 
  hash = 0
 nodeInfo = {ArrayList@2403}  size = 1
  0 = {DefaultNodeInfo@2408} "NodeInfo{, hostname=localhost/127.0.0.1, configPort=0, directServices={CONFIG=8091, QUERY=8093, VIEW=8092, BINARY=11210}, sslServices={CONFIG=18091, QUERY=18093, VIEW=18092, BINARY=11207}}"
 enabledServices = 15
partition = 7620
useFastForward = false
```

**EDIT 2:**

I had a look at the Couchbase Console log and I am constantly getting the following

```
Service 'memcached' exited with status 1. Restarting. Messages: Failed to open library "/Users/luishreis/Downloads/couchbase-server-enterprise_4/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/memcached/stdin_term_handler.so": dlopen(/Users/luishreis/Downloads/couchbase-server-enterprise_4/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/memcached/stdin_term_handler.dylib, 6): image not found
Unable to load extension /Users/luishreis/Downloads/couchbase-server-enterprise_4/Couchbase Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/lib/memcached/stdin_term_handler.so using the config
```

Any help on the matter would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: That is very strange, it seems to indicate that 1) the SDK hashed the key to a vBucket that is far too large (1894 instead of 1024) and 2) that the cluster map is empty. Could you try to put a breakpoint on the exception and see what parameters were used in `nodeIndexForMaster`? (notable `useFastForward`)

Comment: @SimonBaslé I updated the question with the info you requested, although I am not sure if that's what you asked for. I put a breakpoint on the return statement of that function in the couchbase jdk. Also now you have mentioned it, the IndexOutOfBounds error regularly spits out a different index. Usually it is `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 7620, Size: 0`

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your couchbase installation... I'd try a full reinstall